# Postgres 11 JSONB - How to get all distinct values of a field across all elements

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I have a table called `Shipments`:

```
CREATE TABLE shipments
(
      shipmentId numeric,
      metadata jsonb
);
```

Inside the `metaData` column there can exist an array of JSON objects named `stops` which might look something like this:

```
{
  "stops": [
    {
      "stopId": 1,
      "stopType": "Origin"
    },
    {
      "stopId": 2,
      "stopType": "Destionation"
    },
    {
      "stopId": 3,
      "stopType": "Transit"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to query across the table and get all the distinct `stopType` values. I can get all the distinct `stopType` values for the first index in the `stops` array via this simple query:

```
select distinct metadata->'stops'->0->>'stopType' from shipments
```

This almost gives me what I need:

```
╔══════════╗
║ stopType ║
╠══════════╣
║ Origin   ║
╚══════════╝
```

But what I want is:

```
╔══════════════╗
║ stopType     ║
╠══════════════╣
║ Origin       ║
║ Destination  ║
║ Transit      ║
╚══════════════╝
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: please see [mre] and https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql  and add the missing information

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have made the requested changes.

Comment: You say you want "for first index", but your example result is clearly not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements_text`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.e ->> 'stopType' AS "stopType"
FROM shipments AS s
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(s.metadata->'stops') AS a(e);
```

Comment: This looks close to what I need, but I'm getting this error 
 
ERROR:  operator does not exist: shipments -> unknown
LINE 3:    CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(s->'stops') ...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: This works! SELECT DISTINCT a.e ->> 'stopType'::text AS "stopType"
FROM shipments AS s
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(metadata->'stops') AS a(e)

Comment: Sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using JsON and JSONB, you should try to learn more about that [datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE shipments
> (
>       shipmentId numeric,
>       metadata jsonb
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO shipments (metadata) VALUES('{
>   "stops": [
>     {
>       "stopId": 1,
>       "stopType": "Origin"
>     },
>     {
>       "stopId": 2,
>       "stopType": "Destionation"
>     },
>     {
>       "stopId": 3,
>       "stopType": "Transit"
>     }
>   ]
> }')
> ```

> ```
> select distinct metadata->'stops'->0->>'stopType' from shipments
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column? |
> | :------- |
> | Origin   |
> ```

> ```
> create type allstops as ("stopId" int, "stopType" TEXT);
>
> select "stopType" from shipments, jsonb_populate_recordset(null::allstops ,metadata->'stops')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> | stopType     |
> | :----------- |
> | Origin       |
> | Destionation |
> | Transit      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d2ad7b6fc319961f8607ab4e9b102641)*